# The path alias works in two ways - Yii2

Tags: yii2, alias

In `Yii2` advanced, in ***`common/config/bootsrap.php`*** I have added an ***`@alias`*** which is used to store photos,

but there is a problem:

- if the script runs on the frontend - then the folder is created in
  one place - **public_html/uploads/images**
- and if the script runs on the backend - then the folder is created
  elsewhere - **public_html**/admin/**uploads/image**

How to make so that the folder was created only in frontend?

More information:

- [Image with directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w9rJ.png)
- [.htaccess file code for both files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUxjD.png)

Code for: 
**backend**/controllers/ActionThatCreateTheDirecotry

```
$dir = Yii::getAlias("@images") .'/blog/';
FileHelper::createDirectory($dir);
```

Comment: where is your code how are you specifying the path to the `alias`?

Comment: Muhammad thanks for implication. I added more information.

Comment: Where are you setting the alias **`@images`** and how?

Comment: common/config/bootsrap.php:
Yii::setAlias('@images', dirname(dirname(dirname(_DIR_))) . '/uploads/images');

Comment: please update the code in your post

Comment: ok, done (the code and the question is modified).

Comment: Is your backend configured to use the sub-uri admin?

Comment: I maked the next modifications and it's working:
Yii::setAlias('@images', dirname(dirname(dirname(_DIR_))) . '/../uploads/images');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following modifications and it's working:

```
Yii::setAlias('@images', dirname(dirname(dirname(_DIR_))) . '/../uploads/images');
```